# For which deity is the Gayatri Mantra? Why do we chant it, and what exactly does it mean or signify?

Tags: advaita, gayatri-mantra, consciousness, gayatri, savitri

To which deity is the Gayatri Mantra addressed? What exactly does it mean or signify? Why should we chant the Gayatri Mantra ?

Comment: We have almost forgotten the deity.

Comment: This is a very good question. I had this interpretation - that this activates certain nadis or chakras using certain syllable japa and this leads to activation of the sattvik nature of the person chanting.

Comment: To Savitar, the golden (hiraṇyaya), the golden handed (Híraṇya-pāṇi), the golden haired (hiraṇyákéşa), the golden tongued (Híraṇyajihva), the darkness conqueror (tamo-jíte), the solar diety of the Vedic Arya-s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swami Chinmayananda in his book Meditation and Life, Chapter 18 writes,

> This mantra is dedicated to the Lord Savitṛ  . That Savitṛ represents
> Lord Sun is the accepted version, although some scholars protest
> against this interpretation. The sun gives all illumination to the
> world, and any prayer for light should certainly be addressed to the
> source of all light in the material world – the sun. In the
> Bhagavad-gītā Lord Kṛṣṇa says, “The light that pervades the sun and
> the moon is all My light.” Thus, Savitr, the Lord of Gāyatrī, is
> nothing other than the Light of Consciousness, the Infinite, the
> Absolute. ‘We meditate upon the auspicious, godly light of the Lord
> Sun. May that heavenly light illumine the thought flow in our
> intellect’. **In our own inner life, the sun represents the illuminator
> of all experiences, the Ᾱtman. This pure Consciousness in us, around
> which the matter envelopments function – just as the entire solar
> system revolves around the sun – is being invoked to shine more fully
> in our intellect.** If the sun were not there, physical life on earth
> would be impossible. Without Ᾱtman, the matter envelopments would
> become inert. In chanting the Gāyatrī mantra, the devotee is actually
> praying for spiritual unfoldment – ‘May my intellect be steady without
> agitations; may it be clean without the dirt of passions. **May the
> light of Consciousness come to shine forth its radiance through my
> intellect.** Thus, may my perception of the world be clear, my
> discrimination subtle, my judgements correct and quick, my
> comprehension of situations precise and wise’.

He continues to explain the reason, why to chant Gayatri Mantra,

> The Taittirīya Ᾱraṇyaka explains in story form the reason for the
> daily chanting of the Gāyatrī and the offering poured toward the sun.
> On an island called Arunam lived a tribe of devils called Mandehas.
> Every morning these devils conquered all space and almost reached the
> sun, threatening to destroy him. But the water thrown by the Gāyatrī
> japists was lightning-strong striking the devils and forcing them to
> retreat to their islands. **The story is symbolic of events in one’s
> mind. Mind (manas) and body (deha) are the sources of our activities**. With their likes, dislikes,
> emotions, appetites, passions, and cravings, they bring out our
> passionate animal instincts, which try to conquer and destroy the
> spiritual essence – Brahman or the sun – in us. **The essential
> brilliance of the human intellect is clouded by these passions. The
> Gāyatrī japa, with the force of lightning, descends upon them and
> dissipates them.**

Comment: These Mandehas cloud my mind, until I consciously "see" Surya/ and behind him Savitr. Then the light is cast।

Comment: The fire that is the Gayatri, grows in  beautiful hymn of the godly Vishwamitra Gathinah. Hoping that a question on that will add veneration.